# I have to implement Doorkeeper in a spree based application to generate client Id and client secret key from admin panel

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, spree, spree-auth-devise

I am not able to implement it on my project

I want that from admin panel I am able to create client Id and client secret key ruby

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Add doorkeeper gem to the gemfile and run bundle install: `gem 'doorkeeper', '~> 5.6', '>= 5.6.8'`
2. run `rails g doorkeeper:install`. It will create an initializer config file.
3. run `rails g doorkeeper:migration`. This will create migration file for database tables. Run `rails db:migrate` afterwards
4. create route path in `routes.rb` by adding `use_doorkeeper`

After these steps you should be able to use `Doorkeeper::Application` table. After you create a record it'll generate uid & secret columns. I can recommend [this](https://rubyyagi.com/rails-api-authentication-devise-doorkeeper/) tutorial if you face any trouble.